# Why Angular resolver does NOT return any data when returning observable using of() but returns when using of().pipe(delay(1000))

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngxs

My question is just that as in the title. I do not fully understand why does Angular resolver NOT return (does not resolve) any data when the returned object is created using the `of([...someData])` but works when using `of([...someData]).pipe(delay(1000)`

To give a quick example:
resolver:

```
 resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    | Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesSuccess
    | Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesFailed
    | Observable<Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesSuccess | Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesFailed>
    | Promise<Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesSuccess | Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesFailed> 
    {

    this.store.dispatch(new Schedule.FetchAllSportTypes());

    const responseOK: Observable<Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesSuccess> = this.actions$.pipe(ofAction(Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesSuccess));

    const responseError = this.actions$.pipe(
      ofAction(Schedule.FetchAllSportTypesFailed),
      tap(() => this.router.navigate(['']))
    );

    return race(responseOK, responseError).pipe(first());
  }
```

the `this.store.dispatch(new Schedule.FetchAllSportTypes())` calls `fetchAllSportTypes` method:

```
fetchAllSportTypes(): Observable<SportType[]>{

}
```

when the implementation of `fetchAllSportTypes(): Observable<SportType[]>` is the following, the resolver does NOT return any data, it just keeps waiting:

```
fetchAllSportTypes(): Observable<SportType[]>{
  return of([...someData])
}
```

but when the implementation is the following, the resolver does work as expected:

```
fetchAllSportTypes(): Observable<SportType[]>{
      return of([...someData]).pipe(delay(1000))
    }
```

Comment: You must subscribe to your Observable .... I don't see any subscription...

Comment: NGXS automatically subscribes to the fetchAllSportTypes method. That’s actually not the problem

Comment: does it matter how much you delay?
or does it change if for example you only use `tap` with a console output instead of `delay`?

Comment: I don’t think that will matter but it’s easy enough for me to test. I will try with using just one second a see if it works

Comment: it doesnt matter on the value inside delay, as long as it is there, it could be 1 and it still worked. as soon as I took out the `.pipe(delay())` it all broke again

Comment: could you create a demo on stackblitz?